# What does mean @ in server.xml in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

In server.xml I see:

```
<Connector port="@app.port.value@"...
```

What does mean character @ in this context?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is likely a placeholder and will be replaced dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Exactly. In particular, that @ syntax is the traditional way of marking tokens for an [Ant replace](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) task. That suggests that this server.xml is going to be processed with Ant as part of the build process before Tomcat is started.